# Phonegap Barcode Scanner error SetupTask

Tags: android, ant, cordova, phonegap-plugins, barcode-scanner

I'm trying to develop a PhoneGap app and I need a QR Code Scanner. I'm trying to implement this plugin: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/BarcodeScanner, but I'm getting this error from Line 64 in the plugin build.xml file:

```
taskdef class com.android.ant.SetupTask cannot be found using the classloader AntClassLoader[]
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: The code works fine, but I can't build the app.. but it runs just fine on the emulator

Comment: Still post the code. We can't tell what's wrong if we don't have any code to look at. If it works on the emulator, then it must have built, right? So is this when launching the app. Or something else?